# Crystal report error - System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory.

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I keep getting this Crystal report error while trying to view the report from an application hosted in IIS.

The code -

```
    ceEnterpriseService = ceSession.GetService("", "InfoStore")
    ReportApplicationFactory = ceSession.GetService("RASReportFactory").Interface
    ceInfoStore = New InfoStore(ceEnterpriseService)
```

The web server throws an unhandled win exception as soon as it passes "New InfoStore(ceEnterpriseService)" line.

I have Crystal enterprise 10 installed and am using VS 2012/.NET 4.5. I have to use Crystal enterprise 10 since that is being used by the client. I also had a different version installed and un installed some time back which broke some of the reports while I checked in.
Resolved that by asking the clients to load their set of dlls.

Could this error also be an outcome of incorrect versions? How do I check what version is required.
I'm kind of lost in this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. This is fixed, in case someone faces this issue.

There was some issue with the crystal report designer on my development machine. Fixed that and the reports worked fine.